# Android - random byte arrays taking up memory?

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

I was investigating my RAM usage when I discovered an array taking up 14 MB. I decided to investigate it.

[image]

I used Eclipse's MAT to investigate further into exactly what was happening.

[image]

And then further into specifically what was being allocated.

[image]

I discovered this large array (although this was not taking up the 14 MB). Does anyone know why there's this array of random characters and digits? In my code, I do not assign an array that is anywhere related to something that could possibly generate this.

Comment: There's a lot more running than just your code, so you probably have very little chance of affecting those "random" byte arrays.

Comment: I suggest that you read this: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/ ... if you haven't done so already.  Apart from that, we have about zero chance of telling you (accurately) where those arrays are coming from.